# React | input field updated by props change

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 class components.
The former has some dates that can be selected/clicked.
The second one has an input date field that can be also populated with the choice from the first component.

I'm not able to make it possible for the second component to pick a date independently or to set the date when the first one is clicked (a date in it).
I create this small example:

```
export function TestDate(props:{initilaDate:Date|undefined}) {
  const dateString = props.initilaDate?.toISOString().substr(0, 10) || "" 
  const [selectedDate, setDate] = useState(props.initilaDate)

  return <>
    <div>Initial: {dateString} | Selected: {selectedDate?.toLocaleDateString()||""}</div>
    <div>Date1: <input type="date" defaultValue={dateString} value={dateString}  /></div>
    <div>Date2: <input type="date" defaultValue={dateString} value={selectedDate?.toJSON().substr(0, 10)} 
      onChange={evt => setDate(evt.target.valueAsDate || undefined)} /></div>
  </>
}

// assume clickedDate change when user click somewhere on the main component
<TestDate initilaDate={this.state.clickedDate||new Date()} />
```

**Date1** is updated with the initial date passed within props **but it does not change the date itself**.
**Date2** can change the selected date **but its date is not updated when props change**.

I'm using *Props* to pass the new initial date to the second component.
In the real case, I cannot use *useContext* because it's a class component.
I also explored `getDerivedStateFromProps` but is discouraged and I don't like it at all.

I think the right tool is `bind` but I'm not able to make it work.